# NIFI not streaming all messages between KAFKA topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm using NIFI to stream messages between Kafka topics, using NIFI's ConsumeKafka_2_ and PublishKafka_2_6 . The ConsumeKafka_2_6 defined with Offset Reset : earliest .

The source Topic x1 has 22 million messages but only 12 million messages streaming into the new destination Topic x2 .

Topic x1 and Topic x2 have the same definition.

Any idea why not all the 22 million messages streaming into the destination Topic x2 ?

One important thing,the **cleanup.policy** on topics is **compact**

Comment: Check a group offset on Kafka

Comment: I checked ,before the process start Kafka displayed "22 million records behind " , but only 12 million records were transferred at the end of the process.

Comment: Is the group offset after the process the latest?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I found the answer for the missing messages in the destination Topic x2. The messages count showing in the Kafka UI is wrong for Topics with **cleanup policy: compact**. The calculation summing of messages in the Kafka UI for Topic x1 does not consider the gaps of compacted(deleted) messages.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).